# PHP-like static methods in C++ CodeBlocks

Tags: php, c++, visual-studio, codeblocks

I have simple class declaration in C++

```
class A {
    static void foo(void){
       printf("Bar\n");
    }
};
```

In Visual Studio 2013 I can use it by `A::foo()` but in CodeBlocks I get `undefined reference` error. How can I create abstract methods like in PHP (where I don't need to create object to call this methods) in CodeBlocks?

My code (working in Visual Studio 2013): https://github.com/ventaquil/Blake-512

Comment: We would need to see an [mcve] to help you

Comment: @NathanOliver https://github.com/ventaquil/Blake-512

Comment: You ignored the word "Minimal"

Comment: @NathanOliver minimal example is in my question..

Comment: But you minimal example is not compete or verifiable.

Comment: Ofc.. Stop offtop please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with CodeBlocks include method. In Visual I include header file and it's working correctly, but CodeBlocks is stupid and don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like in this example:

Sample.h

```
class Sample
{
    static int boo;
    static void init()
    {
        boo = 1;
    }
}
```

Sample.cpp

```
#include "Sample.h"
int Sample::boo;
```

Usage:

```
#include "Sample.h"
cout << Sample::boo;
```